# getting invalid token from facebook PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my code that checks if the user has authorized the app or not

```
 $customer_id = $facebook->getUser();
    echo 'My customer ID is '.$customer_id;
    echo $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

Even I have removed the app from my facebook it is giving me correct `fb Id` and `appId|secretId` as token,

Any idea what could be the reason, the same code was working fine few hours back, any Idea what could be the reason or how to get refreshed data from fb?

Comment: `appId|secretId` is an _app_ access token – so I doubt that you have a fully logged-in user; seems rather like the user id might still be set, due to some cookies left set on your side … but to get a new user access token, you have initiate the auth flow again.

Comment: @CBroe that is correct the cookies are still left after i clean the cookies things work fine, so how to get rid of this situation?

Comment: @Phillip the other question is by me as well :) that was another scenerio,

Comment: There is no way anyone could help you with the little amount of information you've given.  You need to provide the entire login flow as well.

Comment: Also you're asking the same thing as you are in the other question - which makes this a duplicate.  Your other question is also more informative as it includes a login flow (though not all of it).